# Program paused while thread is being executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver, python-multithreading, chromium-embedded

I have a program that should start a web server (as the thread), and then display it in a CEF Browser (not a thread). But when I start it, it just waits for the thread to stop executing, which it will never do, since its an infinite loop.

```
print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))
webServerThread = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args = ("python -m http.server 8081", ), daemon=True)
webServerThread.start()
webServerThread.join()
print('Initialising CEF')
cef.Initialize()
print('[DEBUG] CreateBrowserSync')
cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/compfile.html")
print('[DEBUG] MessageLoop')
cef.MessageLoop()
```

I have tried to search on stackoverflow and google and I didn't find anything that would help me.

Comment: why not use subprocess????

Comment: remove this "webServerThread.join()"

Comment: your welcome but be carreful to kill the app you run as daemon!

Comment: @NarcisseDoudieuSiewe It runs a sub-process. The thread just waits for a sub-process finish.

Comment: @273K it is not the same thing. subprocess spawns a new process where thread does not. Also joining at the end is not needed as cef.MessageLoop is a blocking action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `webServerThread.join()` immediately after `webServerThread.start()`, your app still have a run flow like a single-thread application. Move `webServerThread.join()` to the end.

```
print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))
webServerThread = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args = ("python -m http.server 8081", ), daemon=True)
webServerThread.start()

print('Initialising CEF')
cef.Initialize()
print('[DEBUG] CreateBrowserSync')
cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="http://127.0.0.1:8081/compfile.html")
print('[DEBUG] MessageLoop')
cef.MessageLoop()

webServerThread.join()
```

Comment: the comments already helped me, but this works as well, thx :)